# What does "go on floors" really mean?

Tags: idioms, terminology, phrase-meaning

When reading movie magazines or news I come across lines like the below:

> - Mr. A's new film goes on floors next month.
> - The actors 2 movies are going on floors later this year.

One can guess the meaning of the phrase *go on floor* from the above lines but I am not sure what exactly it means, and couldn't find it in any dictionary.

Comment: It's not a familiar idiom in the US.  I'm guessing it's a foreign idiom meaning "go in theaters".

Comment: (Though the term "go on floors" is, I believe, used in retail businesses, to describe the act of placing merchandise on display.)

Answer (score 4):

The *floor* here is a bit of film jargon, referring to the floor of a studio. As explained in *[A Dictionary of Confusable Phrases](https://books.google.com/books?id=LAKQCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA252)* (2010) by Yuri Dolgopolov, *on the floor* means

> 1. in a movie or TV studio: *I'll make a shooting script…. It'll be something you can go on the floor with.* 2. *(of a film)* being shot; in production: *At Elstree, only one film,* the Guinea Pig, *is on the floor*

(it is in the "confusable phrases" dictionary in contrast to *on the shop floor*).

The OED similarly has, under *floor* (n.1):

> d. *spec.* The floor of a studio where films or television programmes are shot; hence used *allusively*: *(a)* a film or television studio; *(b)* in phr. ***on the floor***, of a film: in production.

Thus, a film that is *going on the floor* or *going on floors* is one going into production, i.e. that has graduated from development and pre-production. In Western entertainment media, however, this phrasing seems to be rather rare. Its use in popular culture seems to be limited to the Indian subcontinent. A Hollywood movie doesn't go *on the floor*, it goes *into [production](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Movie_Making_Manual)* or *starts shooting*.